# Turning off Log4j2 by setting Root level to "off" doesnt work

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j, junit4

I have a problem with logging within Junit tests.

In log4j2.xml, I have changed `<Root level="info">` to `<Root level="off">`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c{1.} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="off">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
        <!-- hibernate debugging -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But it doesn't help, I still get the same amount of logs. I need to make the logs dissapear to make progress in an test performance investigation, to be able to run my own allways despised `System.out.println()` in some of the tests. How can I achive that?

Comment: You haven't said what is being logged. You should verify that what is being logged matches the pattern you specified. In fact, you might change your pattern to something weird just to verify whether the logs are coming through Log4j. You might have some other logging framework present that is doing the logging.